# Localstorage is cleared within one test in cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a simple test that fails because of clearing the local storage in the middle of it.

This is my beforeEach block

```
beforeEach(() => {
    interceptLogin()
    interceptProfile()

    cy.visit('/')
    cy.getLocalStorage('lang').then(($lang) => {
      cy.log($lang)
    })
```

And this is the testcase

```
it.only('[C306] Should redirect user to reset password page on click on "forget password?" link', () => {
    cy.getLocalStorage('lang').then(($lang) => {
      cy.log($lang)
    })
    loginPage.clickForgetPassword()
    cy.getLocalStorage('lang').then(($lang) => {
      cy.log($lang)
    })
    resetPasswordPage.assertResetPasswordPageURL(appLanguage)
  })
```

The log statement in the beforeEach returns a value, the first statement inside it returns the value successfully while the 3rd returns null.

This null causes a problem in redirection in the system, the function `click forget password()` just in a click on an anchor which keeps the local storage saved normally when I try the scenario manually.

I can fix the test temporarily by setting the localstorage value myself but I don't get why this issue happens.

[image]

Comment: I wanted to clarify if this issue is only limited to a cypress run and not manually.

Comment: Yes, manually things go fine, I found local storage values and the redirection happens correctly @jjhelguero

Comment: Have a go with [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events#why) `.realClick()`.

Comment: @Fody `.realClick()` doesn't fix the problem unfortunately